# Hide add to cart button and add custom content after it in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I've added a 'Customize Now' button and few dropdowns after the 'add to cart' button using `woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button`.

But now when I try to hide the 'add to cart' button (which I have to for a specific scenario my website need) using `woocommerce_is_purchasable`, the 'Customize Now' button and dropdowns are also hidden. Is there any proper order/sequence to do this?

Filter to add the Customize button and dropdowns:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', array($this, 'pn_get_calc_and_customize_btn'));
```

Filter to remove the add to cart button:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', array($this, 'pn_hide_add_to_cart_button'), 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As add-to-cart templates display condition is:

```
if ( ! $product->is_purchasable() ) {
    return;
}
```

**2 ways:**

1) Use instead `woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook with a **priority between `30` and `40`**:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', array($this, 'pn_get_calc_and_customize_btn'), 35 );
```

Then your function output code should be embedded in a custom `<form>` and you will need to add some more code to save the data in cart or elsewhere…

---

2) To remove cart button, use `woocommerce_product_is_in_stock` filter hook instead of `woocommerce_is_purchasable` so you will have to change a bit your hooked function code too...

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_is_in_stock', array($this, 'pn_hide_add_to_cart_button'), 10, 2);
```

Comment: Can you help me out with one more challenge that I'm facing with product image?

Comment: this is URL to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48761473/replace-product-image-temporarily-on-all-the-pages-across-the-user-session

Comment: @AkashAgrawal It's a bit too complicated (for me) what you are asking there, meaning that this is a real development like…

Comment: Yeah... It's getting my nerve wreck.. been trying to implement this from days

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions here:

The first one will be to try to add the priority to your `add_action()` as well. As per documentation, the lower the number, the earlier the execution. I would try to add a greater priority to `add_action()` and try to force the `woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button` to be executed after your filter. However, I don't know if removing the button also inhibits the filter (it might be).

Another suggestion I may have is to override the default template for the page (i don't know if you're editing the shop page or the single_product page) and have some `if{}else{}` login in there to show hide buttons based on the situation.

I don't know if either of these solutions is any good for you but this was just my tough and how I would tackle it.

Hope it helps in any way

Comment: I'm editing the 'single_product' page and Yes, I do have if{} else{} in place to check if the product is of my custom type that I created. The problem I'm facing here is setting woocommerce_is_purchasable to false destroys the add to cart button and I'm using woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button to add content. There's no add to cart button, as a result, the content that I'm adding is also destroyed. I've to place Customize button right next to add to cart for a reason. Setting priority doesn't seem to work. Is there any other workaround?

Comment: Ok so if i got it correctly you want to set it to not purchasable because you want to customise it and then you're going to add the custom product to the cart yourself, correct? Can't it be customisable with product variables? As I think that setting it to not purchasable will also prevent you from adding it to the cart in the first place, and when you do you will probably face another issue which is woocommerce not adding it to the cart, you will have to set it back to purchasable at that point...

Comment: You got it somewhere correct. I want to first customize the product and then the add to cart button should be visible. But here customize button will let me edit the image of the product. This will be a label designing website (T-shirt is just a dummy product, there will be business cards instead of T-shirts).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @NIck, you could help me with one more thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48761473/replace-product-image-temporarily-on-all-the-pages-across-the-user-session